# Okidata MB760, MB492, etc. PJL commands

Tags: printing, printers, pjl

I have used PJL commands with some HP printers to set printer control panel display message and duplexing of PDF documents. I have some customers with similar requirements using Okidata MB760 and MB492 machines. I know the Okidata machines support PJL, but it appears to be a different set of codes from HP (as is the case with every manufacturer - no standard for PJL except the entry/exit codes). Okidata support was unable to provide a programmer's manual or a PJL reference. Does anyone have information specific to these machines or (since each manufacturer tends to use the same codes with slight variations for a long time) for any other Okidata MB machines?

No response, not even comments. I did some testing via "print to file" in Windows and it looks like I can extract enough PJL from there to do what I need to do. But I still hold some small bit of hope that someone - maybe a helpful insider at Okidata? - will post some sort of PJL reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can download a program called [PCL Paraphernalia](http://www.pclparaphernalia.eu/) which allows you to connect and execute some PJL commands.

It's not the sleekest of interfaces but the **Status Readback Utility** option should allow you to retrieve all the allowed variables from the printer

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting. I will try this next time I am on-site at a customer with a PJL-capable printer. Holding off on approval/upvote until I see if it works :-)